# Loop through between two integers

Tags: excel, loops, vba

Please help me to fix this,

*Requirement:*

Pasting data from sheet 1 to sheet x and skip to next page.

*Problem:*

I am unable to run the loop between 2 integers at a time.
I want to run the loop between x and y every time.But the written code is finishing x first and the going to y.

Please check below code and help me with u r ideas. Thank you.

```
Sub sbCopyValueToAnotherSheet()
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

For y = 2 To 11
 For x = 2 To 50

Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, y).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("F6")
 y = y + 1
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, y).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("P6")
y = y + 1
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, y).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("P7")
y = y + 1
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, y).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("F8")
y = y + 1
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, y).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("P8")
y = y + 1
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, y).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("F9")
y = y + 1
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, y).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("P9")
y = y + 1
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, y).Copy 
Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("F10")
y = y + 1
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, y).Copy 
Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("P10")
y = y + 1
ActiveSheet.Next.Select

Next x
Next y

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the y = y + 1, the next y statement increments y, you don't have to

Comment: Each time the loop repeats and x increments, the destination cells will be overwritten. Do you need to additionally increment the addresses of the destination cells?

Comment: I don't understand your problem, and I am not sure what you are trying to do,  but, the `y+1`'s seem surperfluous; in nested loops, the inner loop will run to completion for each iteration of the outer loop.   Perhaps you merely need to reverse your loops?  But, of course, your destination will still be the same each time through the loop.

Comment: To echo @RonRosenfeld - Why are you looping and pasting to the *same* range? It would be the same as just copying the very last `x` and `y` value, `...Cells(50,11)` and pasting there.  Can you perhaps include a sample table of data, and clarify what you're trying to do? Looking at this I'm almost certain there's a more efficient way of doing what it is you want.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response, Actually I have data in Sheet 1 range of B2:L50, and i want input B2:L2 (One row, 10 values) into another sheet which i have a Form of test report. (This sheet range is F6:F10 for first 5 numbers and P6 to P10 is for next 5 numbers. So in sheet 1 one row having 10 numbers, I want to copy them to another sheet in above mentioned range and jump to next sheet, then 2nd row data should copy to that after complete 3rd row 3rd sheet. This what i need please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to copy 50 rows from Sheet1 into the same cells on 50 different sheets, try this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub sbCopyValueToAnotherSheet()
    Dim x As Long, wsM As Worksheet, wsCount As Long

    wsCount = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    Set wsM = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For x = 2 To 50
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(x)
            .Range("F6") = wsM.Cells(x, 2)
            .Range("F7") = wsM.Cells(x, 3)
            .Range("F8") = wsM.Cells(x, 4)
            .Range("F9") = wsM.Cells(x, 5)
            .Range("F10") = wsM.Cells(x, 6)
            .Range("P6") = wsM.Cells(x, 7)
            .Range("P7") = wsM.Cells(x, 8)
            .Range("P8") = wsM.Cells(x, 9)
            .Range("P9") = wsM.Cells(x, 10)
            .Range("P10") = wsM.Cells(x, 11)
        End With
        If x = wsCount Then Exit Sub
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response, Actually I have data in Sheet 1 range of B2:L50, and i want input B2:L2 (One row, 10 values) into another sheet which i have a Form of test report. (This sheet range is F6:F10 for first 5 numbers and P6 to P10 is for next 5 numbers. So in sheet 1 one row having 10 numbers, I want to copy them to another sheet in above mentioned range and jump to next sheet, then 2nd row data should copy to that after complete 3rd row 3rd sheet. This what i need please Help me.

Comment: @sudheerkumar: I made a change as per your comment. Hope this helps